# Prometheus Metrics - Use for autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I've setup prometheus to collect metrics from my pods and nodes.
I've also setup the prometheus custom metrics adapter.

How can I use those metrics provided by prometheus to autoscale my pods ? I tried to google it but I only find custom pods that provides their metrics on their /metrics url. I would like to be able to autoscale any of my pods that already have a prometheus metric based on the cpu or memory usage.

I can visualize all the metrics in grafana for all my pods and nodes but can't find a way to use it with autoscale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an HPA (Horizontal Pod Autoscaler)

More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-multiple-metrics)

[This is a good tool](https://github.com/stefanprodan/k8s-prom-hpa) showing you how to use an HPA with custom metrics either using a the K8s metrics server or Prometheus.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot